# Converting Sram Force 1 to Sram Force 22

Tags: gears, chainring, sram, groupsets

I am buying a Sram Force 1 groupset with a new bike and I cannot test it before buying. In the case I really dislike the gearing steps issues, how difficult/costly would it be to convert to Sram Force 22 which has two chainrings?

Comment: May be impossible - totally depends if your frame can take a front mech or not, either with a mounting in the right place or by using a band-on front mech which requires a round seat tube and clearances.

Comment: Yes in my case the frame is ready for a front mech

Comment: Unless you live far from a bike shop, find a supplier who'll let you try before you buy.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you will be looking at a new crank, front derailleur and left hand shifter; and possibly a cassette.

I think you'll be OK running the Force 1 rear derailleur with double chainrings, unless you are getting a long cage version, in which case the minimum cassette size is 11-36 ([source](https://www.sram.com/sram/road/products/sram-force-1-rear-derailleur#specs)). If you want a narrower cassette - which your question implies - you'd want a mid or short cage that support 11-25 and 11-28.

You are looking at considerable cost - half a groupset. Cranks are easy to swap, left shifter not too hard - but you'll need a brake bleed for the front brake which is a pain. Front derailleur is not too bad (make sure the bike comes with front derailleur mounting options!) It does all add up to a significant effort though.

I see questions on this site about buying a bike then swapping out some big chunk of it from time to time. My advice is *buy the bike that you want in the first place!*. I'd at least try to get a test ride on a SRAM 1x bike before committing.

Comment: Yes you're right I guess even the driver body must be changed (sram xd if 10-42 cassette). Should be an expensive endeavour. I'm interested by the 1x perks but would be best to try it beforehand indeed

Comment: He won't need a new crank, just a 2x spider and a pair of chainrings.

Comment: Also, Force 1 RD is 1x only because it's X-Horizon, see [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/24681/9215).

Comment: @Klaster_1 Thanks for the extra info - I was suspicious that the RD would not work but could not see a reason why on my initial look at the specs